# How to get rid of this loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've developed a simple login system in JS. When the password, the username or both are incorrect it's suposed to show an alert but now it shows 4. I know it is because of the for loop but I don't know how to get rid of it without breaking all the code. Thanks in advance =)

I leave here the piece of code:

```
function getName() {
      var user = document.getElementById('Username').value;
      var pass = document.getElementById('Password').value;
      
      for (let f = 0; f < arr.length; f++) {
        if (user == arr[f][0] && pass == arr[f][1]) {              
          document.write("Welcome back ", user, ", we've missed you");
        }
        if (user == arr[f][0] && pass != arr[f][0])  {
          alert("Your password is incorrect");
        }
        else if (user != arr[f][0] && pass == arr[f][1]) {
          alert("Your username is incorrect");
        }
        else {
          alert("Unnexistant account");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The delete key is a good start (I kid I kid) --- What is `arr`? Is it an array of **users and passwords**?!

Comment: What is `arr` and why is there a loop in the first place? At a guess I'd assume that you have all your users and passwords stored in there? In which case you cannot remove the loop, but you should definitely add `break;` statements in the appropriate places

Comment: Can you post the `arr`?

Comment: document.write() only accepts one argument ... you want `+` not comma to build the string. BUT it also wipes out everything in the page when called after page has loaded

Comment: Yes, arr is an Array for usernames and passwords. I'm sorry if I write something incorrectly, I am barely new at this and sometimes is difficult for me.

Comment: The arr = [[user1, password1] , [user2, password2] , [user3, password3] , [user4, password4]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct is correct, and a for loop is probably not ideal here. It is hard to read and debug and it's also kind of ugly. If you want to stick with it, the other answers show you how.

Assuming `arr` is an array of usernames & passwords, you can convert this into a `Map` and remove your loop completely.

```
const map = new Map();
arr.map(e => m.set(e[0], e[1]));

try {
  if (map.get(user) === pass) {
    document.write("welcome back " + user + ", we missed you.");
  } else {
    // although this might be too much info from a security standpoint.
    document.write("incorrect password"); 
  }
} catch (e) {
  document.write("could not find user.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for answering the question =D

Comment: You're welcome. If you like one answer in particular (whatever one that might be), please mark it as the correct answer for the answerer's sake and for whoever looks at this question in the future! Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `break;` after each document.write or alert statements.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback really apreciate it :D

Answer (score 1):

If the username for one account is wrong, you don't want to tell them their account doesn't exist until you check it for every single account:

```js
function getName() {
    var user = document.getElementById('Username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('Password').value;

    for (let f = 0; f < arr.length; f++) {
        if (user == arr[f][0] && pass == arr[f][1]) {              
            document.write("Welcome back ", user, ", we've missed you");
            return; // exit from the function since we've found an account
        }
        if (user == arr[f][0] && pass != arr[f][0])  {
            alert("Your password is incorrect");
            return; // exit from the function since we've found a username match
        }
    }
    // couldn't find match, alert
    alert("Your account does not exist.");
}
```